# Phrasal verb/expression for "bring people together somewhere"

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

Is there a phrasal verb or expression to express the idea of bringing people together somewhere, other than explicitly using "people" in the sentence?

I am looking for something that already implies it's people we are talking about:

> Let's bring people to the party.
>   Let's "expression ->" party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not crystal clear. If I understand you correctly: the phrase 'get together' means 'to meet some other person(s)  somewhere'.

Often, perhaps even usually, the meeting will be for something fun or entertaining, but serious work can also be implied.

"Let's get together!" Context: it was great to see you today after all these years and I'm happy to hear you're back in town. Let's plan to meet [e.g. for drinks or a coffee] at some time in the near future.

"Are they going to get together after the meeting?"

Could mean:

When the meeting is over, are they going to meet afterwards [e.g. for drinks]?

But it could also mean:

When the (public) meeting is over, are they going to meet in private afterwards to discuss their differences and try to settle the dispute amicably?

Comment: I like "Let's get together". "Let's get together for the party", thanks

Comment: "Let's get together for the party" would be understood but it is not perfectly idiomatic because "get together" has an IMPLICIT or GENERIC or INDEFINITE purpose not an EXPLICIT or SPECIFIC or DEFINITE purpose.  You could say "The party is at 8PM. Let's get together beforehand" or "Let's get together for drinks" but you would not say "Let's get together tonight at 5pm at Cafe Nola".

Comment: If you mean "let's all meet at such-and-such place so we can go to the party together" you would say "Let's meet up for the party."  You could also say "Let's get together for *a* party"-- that is, at some indefinite time in the near future.

Comment: Then there's "let's come together" (usually "for" something).  A bit more grandiose, "eventful".

Answer (score 1):

> Let's party.
>
> Let's have a party.

After all, without other people, there won't be a "party", there will be just you, since the word `party` implies more than one person.